# Best methodology for encrypting a password

Tags: c#, password-encryption

I read so many articles left and right about password encryption but it seems that they are **mostly 2-4 years old**.

I wonder if there have been new findings on what methodology has already been cracked and mainly what's the **more secured way** to **encrypt a password** for user logins on a public website today in 2013.

The main goal is to do a ONE WAY (not decryptable) secured encryption so using hash or not, using salt or not, that's what I'm hoping to learn here.

======================
Other question:
Does it make sense to change the SALT for each password instead of using the same one for all?

Comment: Salt + hash with `scrypt` probably, but this is substantially subjective.

Comment: Generally salt-hashing and `RIJENDAEL-256`/`ASA512` is good. bcrypt I think is standard still.

Comment: The technique hasn't really changed in the last 2-4 years.

Comment: Be careful with bcrypt or scrypt - they seem like great options, and I've never read anything bad about either, but last I saw, neither had "official" .NET implementations.

Comment: As long as up-to-date resources don't say that the hash you plan to use has been cracked, 2-4 year old password encryption content should be perfectly up-to-date. Things don't move that quickly in that field.

Comment: Cryptology is not generally a rapidly moving field.  Just use a password hashing algorithm and not a verification algorithm like MD5 or the SHA family.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin Whats wrong withe the "SHA family" ?

Comment: @JoeEnos I've found http://www.zer7.com/software.php?page=cryptsharp
At Desigeek: Not sure why it's getting downvoted.

Comment: @Magnus They're good hashes for things like file verification, but they are too fast to run to be ideal for password hashing.  Good password hashing algorithms do things like run other hashes for a lot of iterations to get the processing requirement up.  That's not to say SHA-2 is inappropriate - if properly salted it's a lot better than a lot of hash functions, but ones like scrypt/bcrypt are better.

Comment: @Developer Regarding that implementation, that's why I said "official" - there are unofficial ones like this out there, but I don't know if any trustworthy cryptography experts have validated them, and I wouldn't have the slightest clue how to validate their source code myself. I won't use cryptography code that isn't either part of the .NET framework, or at least validated by an expert who I trust, so I'll go with [PBKDF2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx), until I feel comfortable with a bcrypt implementation.

Comment: @JoeEnos ..that's a good point. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an excelent site that talks about password hashing.  I think it covers all of your questions: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: Please mark as answer if you think it answers your question. Please also provide more information from the website that answers the question as links will eventually die.

Comment: Good link, it does not mention `peppering` but otherwise everything is there. Like the source code too.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it make sense to change the SALT for each password instead of using the same one for all

A salt needs to be a different random string for each and every password.
Note the word **random**.
Usernames, the system clock and other low entropy data is not advisable.

> using salt or not,

Hashing password without using a salt leaves you open to parallelization of the attack.
Not only does it allow rainbow tables, but it also allows the attacker to hash easy to guess passwords and compare the hash against all entries in the database.
This means that an unsalted database with 1,000,000 records in a million times easier to crack than one with 1 entry.
-Not good-

**Read up on the subject at security.stackexchange**
The leading expert on these subjects stalks the ranks at https://security.stackexchange.com

The canonical answer to your question is here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords

Thomas Pornin is a well known cryptographer and writes very informative, insightful and entertaining answers; check out his user profile.  https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin

And don't miss out on the [Chimps](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33470/what-technical-reasons-are-there-to-have-low-maximum-password-lengths/33471#33471).